# Generating random binary array in numpy with varying probabilities given by indices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, covariance-matrix

I have a symmetric matrix A, with `A.shape = (30, 30)`, and each row of `A` is associated with one of 3 unique labels `[0, 1, 2]`.

I have another matrix M:

```
m1 = .9
m2 = .1

M = np.array([[m1, m2, m2],
              [m2, m1, m2],
              [m2, m2, m1]])
```

I'd like to make a new array `X` with shape `(30, 3)`. Call each row of this array `Xi`, and its associated label `k` (with k being 0, 1, or 2).

I'd like the `ith` element of `Xi` to be 1 with probability m1 if `i == k` and m2 if `i != k`.

I have some working code written up to do this that uses a nested for-loop, but I'd like to do this with pure numpy. Any suggestions?

Here is the current inefficient implementation, skipping the part where I define `A`, `labels`, and `M`:

```
n_communities = 3
X = []
for i, _ in enumerate(A):  # A is a 2d array, shape (30, 30), symmetric
    Xi = []
    k = labels[i]  # labels is an array of length 30, each labels corresponds to a row of A
    for ii in range(n_communities):
        p = M[k, ii]
        Xi.append(np.random.choice([1, 0], p=[p, 1-p]))
    X.append(Xi)
X = np.array(X)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sample M1 and M2 independently and just insert M1 into M2 at the right positions given by the labels.

```
m1_arr = np.random.choice([1, 0], p=[m1, 1-m1], size=(N))
m2_arr = np.random.choice([1, 0], p=[m2, 1-m2], size=(N, 3))
m2_arr[np.arange(N), labels] = m1_arr
X = m2_arr
```